# PHP/XAMPP Using DirectoryIterator class does not display the images

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, xampp

Hi I am using a Wordpress custom theme, and in my footer I would like to display a series of random images chosen out of a folder. For now I have my path set correctly and my output of the path is correct. Then I insert the path in an `<img>` tag and it only displays broken image icons.

When I inspect, the image path is correct and the image names are there. However, when I click on the image link inside the inspect element box to view it I get an Access Denied! Error 403 on my tab where I am trying to display the image. I have done extensive research on this now and I have tried so many different approaches.

At one point I tried changing Xampp settings to `allow all` in `httpd-vhosts.conf` and `httpd-xampp.conf`. None of those worked. Then I started wondering if it could be a WordPress issue, but I am not sure how to figure that one out, despite all my research.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
$path = dirname(__DIR__, 2) . '/uploads/footer-img/';

//this outputs pathname of C:\xampp7\htdocs\project\wp-content/uploads/footer-img/

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {

        echo $fileinfo->getBasename() . "\n";
        echo $fileinfo->getBasename('.jpg') . "\n";

        $r = $path . $fileinfo->getBasename();

        //this below outputs my directory with the image.jpg name

        echo $r;

        //this outputs broken image icons

        echo '<img src="' . $r . '"/>'; 

    }
}
```

Comment: The starting sentence reminds me of [random.cat](http://random.cat)

Comment: If the image is not displayed then the path is _not_ correct, either not being generated correctly or image not displayable altogether. Can you just build URL by hand and open image in browser? Once you get that working compare with what you are generating for it.

Comment: can you show an example of the output `$r`?

Comment: @RamRaider my output is `C:\xampp7\htdocs\project\wp-content/uploads/footer-img/`

Comment: @Rarst I have tried using the URL but keep getting the error `Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: DirectoryIterator::__construct(http://localhost:7777/site/wp-content/uploads/footer-img/): failed to open dir: not implemented`. My output for the URL is `http://localhost:7777/site/wp-content/uploads/footer-img/`

Comment: The webserver will not serve files from the local filesystem like that - the files need to be either within the directory structure of the server document root or within aliased directories. As the path is within the `wordpress` content directory I think the path to each image need only be `/uploads/footer-img/` ie `'/uploads/footer-img/banana.jpg'` etc

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up local paths and web paths.

`C:\xamp...` is a local path. Anything that works with your filesystem can access it. *Your browser can't*.

`http://localhost...` is a web path, handled by your web server. This is *the point* of webserver. Browser can access it, things that works with filesystem can't.

To show images in your page you need to be producing *web* paths for them, according to your web server configuration.